# Is there a way to ignore toJson for a field based on other fields in freezed class?

Tags: flutter, dart, json-serializable, flutter-freezed

I managed to ignore fields adding `includeIfNull: false` and `toJson: ignore` writing ignore function as `T? ignore<T>(dynamic _) => null;`.
What I want to achieve is to include field "id" only if "variants" is an empty array, otherwise include its value.

Here is my code:

```
T? ignore<T>(dynamic _) => null;

@freezed
class ProductDto with _$ProductDto {
  @JsonSerializable(includeIfNull: false)
  factory ProductDto({
    @JsonKey(name: "_id") required String? id,
    @JsonKey(toJson: ignore) required bool? isValidated,
    required String? category,
    required List<Map<String, dynamic>>? variants,
    required int? quantity,
    @JsonKey(name: "_updatedDate", toJson: ignore) required String? updatedDate,
    required double? price,
  }) = _ProductDto;
```

Can you please give me some help?

Thanks